# Detect events when system monitor is turn on/off by user or automatically turn off of monitor

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, wndproc

I am using c# winform application.(Window 7 OS)
There are some actions which needs to performed while system monitor is turned off/ on by user or automatically turned off by system
So is there any event to hook those actions?

i have tried for `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` event and listed for suspend and resume .But it is not get fired for monitor turn off or on.
And also suggested to use `WM_POWERBROADCAST` message under the `PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE` notification.
Can anyone share  the code how the monitor turn on or off is captured using above `WM_POWERBROADCAST` message in `WndProc`.

Thanks 
Padma Yeddula